# Is there a way to Link a parent to a group of work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I'm using Excel to bulk edit a group of work items in TFS 2012.

I can add a Link to a Parent work item on each record, but only if I do it line-by-line.

Is there a way that I can link a Parent to a group of work items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by changing my query to result a Tree View, and also include the Parent work items.

Comment: How Seth? I am doing this, but it still doesn't seem to let me do this? I tried copying and pasting below the parent I wanted, but it hasn't worked...

Comment: Ignore me - I was exporting from a query that was in a tree list - NOT the same thing. For anyone else being silly like me... When in Excel, click "Add Tree Level" within the Team menu. This converts it all for you.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks Britt Wescott.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go the other direction.  If you open the parent work item and add a 'Child' link, you can specify a list of work item ids to make children.
[image]

Comment: This is a great backup solution if you're limited to just working from within Visual Studio.

Comment: This works fantastically if you create a query that gives you the stories you're looking for first. ++